# Rails I18n, placeholder of the response object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

On Rails i18n, How should I organize  the attribute placeholder of the response object?

I'm developing JSON API.
For example, `/api/v1/books/:id` returns an object like this.

```
{
  id: integer,
  name: string,
  author_name: string
}
```

If the author of the book is deleted or absent, I want to return `Unknown Author` string as the value of `author_name`.
And I want to manage the string `Unknown Author` with I18n.
Which namespace is it good to place the placeholder?

I'm considering to put it under `view`. like this,

```
views:
  books:
    show:
      unknown_author: Unknown Author
```

Answer (score 0):

Locale files can be organised as per the rails conventions. So the config/locales directory will be:

```
|-defaults
|---es.rb
|---en.rb
|-models
|---book
|-----es.rb
|-----en.rb
|-views
|---defaults
|-----es.rb
|-----en.rb
|---books
|-----es.rb
|-----en.rb
|---users
|-----es.rb
|-----en.rb
|---navigation
|-----es.rb
|-----en.rb
```

And to access these locales, we need to tell rails explicitly:

```
# config/application.rb
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

So in the books views locale file, we can write:

```
    show:
      unknown_author: Unknown Author
```